# optional split string ascii char

Tags: xamarin.forms, text, cell, screen-orientation

Is there a ascii char (non printable) to suggest where to split a string when needed. This in order to show in a cell correctly, even when the screen is rotated. I use buttons in a 5x2 grid in this example.

[image: vertical]
[image: horizontal]

So, "powerslave" change to "power slave" when the text is wrapped to fit into the cell incase the screen is vertical.

eg. "stalingrad" does not fit into a cell, so I would like the have
"staling grad" when the screen is vertical.

I want to use it for a xamarin android app. Now xamarin (4.8) makes
"stalingra d" or "powerslav e". I do not have any control because there is no wrapping feedback.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow you. Can you elaborate on your problem?

Comment: Do you mean you want to store text with a non-printable character so that when you display it your "rendering code" will split the string automatically? If I understand correctly and you are using Xamarin.Forms then you can just have your string stored as "power|slave" then use a value converter to invoke `string.Replace()` to change the pipe for a space and then bind it to the `Text` property of a `Label`.

Comment: @CodingLumis, That would be a good solution if I can do that at the level where the text is wrapped to fit the cell width. It is my first app, it is a too deep dive into xamarin for me to figure this out.

Comment: Are the items in your grid `Label`s or `Button`s? I can think of several ways to achieve what you want of varying complexity to implement but I'm holding off posting an answer until I'm sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only character that can wrap text in xamarin forms is the 0x20 space char.

So, I updated a TTF font. I 0x20 copied space to the underscore and modified the space char 0x20 to 0 horizontal width.

How to use custom forts I found here (by [Gerald Versluis](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/embedded-fonts-xamarin-forms/)).

Now I can parse any text. Replace any " " with "_ ", and whenever a wrap is allowed I can use a " ".

```
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Aces_ High" />
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Agents_ of_ Steel" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Break ing_ the_ Law" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Fast_ as_ a_ Shark" />
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="fht_ Bells_ Tolls" />
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="Holy_ Diver" />
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Mad_ House" />
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="Power slave" />
        <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="Symp_ of_ De struct ion"  />
        <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="Stalin grad" />
        <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="t_ Number_ ot_ Beast" />
        <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="Stop" />
```

Then I get this result. Actually, I would expect this functionality would be in the xamarin platform.

[image: vertical] [image: horizontal]

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can change the data source of above CollectionView based on the orientation of the device Orientation.

**First**,for how to detect the orientation of the device, you can override method `OnSizeAllocated` in your page.

```
    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

        if (Height > Width)
        {
            viewModel.LoadPortraitData();
        }
        else {
            viewModel.LoadLandscapeData();
        }
    }
```

For more, check [Device Orientation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/device-orientation?tabs=windows).

**Second** ,according to your need, we can use [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/) to display the string list. And we can display its items in a vertical grid by setting its `ItemsLayout` property to `VerticalGrid`.

```
  <CollectionView ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 2"  
                    ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
```

I have made a simple demo,you can refer to the following code:

```
<StackLayout Margin="20">
    <CollectionView ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 2"  
                    ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
    
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

The code of **VerticalGridTextPage.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class VerticalGridTextPage : ContentPage
{

    MyViewModel viewModel;

    public VerticalGridTextPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        viewModel = new MyViewModel();
        this.BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

        if (Height > Width)
        {
            viewModel.LoadPortraitData();
        }
        else {
            viewModel.LoadLandscapeData();
        }
    }
}
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();


    public void LoadLandscapeData()
    {
        items.Clear();

        items.Add("power  slave");
        items.Add("staling   grad");
    }

    public void LoadPortraitData() {
        items.Clear();
        items.Add("powerslave");
        items.Add("stalinggrad");
    }

    public MyViewModel() {
        LoadPortraitData();
    }
}
```

For more, check: [Vertical grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#vertical-grid).